# Active Directory WMI Event Watcher for a modification on a group within in specific OU

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Powershell question, I want to register a WMI Event watcher to monitor an AD group modification and I am getting a WMI quota violation. Any thoughts on how to do this or optimize the WQL query?

```
$query = "Select * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent Within 10 Where TargetInstance ISA 'ds_group' AND TargetInstance.DS_distinguishedName like '%VPSA_Exchange_Mailbox_Groups%'"
```

The OU I want to watch is the one that is contained in the DN, but maybe there is a better way? Thanks!

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use Object Access Auditing?

Comment: Would that need to be on the DC? I don't have access to those unfortunately, I'm an OU admin for our division but that's about it.

Comment: You'd need to enable auditing, and set a SACL on that group for write access.  Any update to it will log an event in the Security Event Log.